# How to use a project in one code base/local repository(git) on a different solution from different code base/local repository(git)

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to migrate to TFS 2017 with GIT. Earlier I have the following code base structure

```
$ (TFS Root node)
 -A
   -A1
   -A2
   -A3
   -A.sln   
 -B
   -B1
   -B2
   -B.Sln
   -BA.Sln
```

Due to my team structure in the org, we have A.sln to develop core framework. We have B.Sln to develop deliverable using the A's binaries. However for debugging purpose we have B.Sln which loads all the projects from A's code base and also B's code base.

How can we leverage the same when I migrate to TFS 2017 and GIT as source control.

in BA.Sln will have the project A1 and A2 loading based on relative path. how to use achieve this when working with GIT?

Answer (score -1):

**To migrate from TFVC to Git**, please refer to this link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/import-from-tfvc

I suggest that you could package projects under A.sln to Nuget packages. Then [upload these packages to TFS feed](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/get-started-nuget). TFS could be used as a Nuget server.

So you could install these packages in B.sln to use those assemlies. The advantage is that you doesn't need to care about the migrate these solutions to follow these structure.